# C# Begin Send within a foreach loop issue

Tags: c#, sockets, foreach

I have a group of "Packets" which are custom classed that are coverted to byte[] and then sent to the client. When a client joins, they are updated with the previous "Catch Up Packets" that were sent previous to the user joining. Think of it as a chat room where you are updated with the previous conversations.

My issue is on the client end, we do not receive all the information; Sometimes not at all..

Below is pseudo c# code for what I see

code looks like this.

```
lock(CatchUpQueue.SyncRoot)
{
     foreach(Packet packet in CatchUpQueue)
     {
           // If I put Console.WriteLine("I am Sending Packets"); It will work fine up to (2) client sockets else if fails again.
          clientSocket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(EndSend), data);
     }
}
```

Is this some sort of throttle issue or an issue with sending to many times: ie: if there are 4 packets in the queue then it calls begin send 4 times.

I have searched for a topic similiar and I cannot find one. Thank you for your help.

Edit: I would also like to point out that the sending between clients continues normally for any sends after the client connects. But for some reason the packets within this for loop are not all sent.

Comment: When you create the socket, are you doing UDP or TCP as the protocol type?  UDP does NOT have a delivery guarantee and can be missed.

Comment: Does your callback method check for any errors? You may want to set a breakpoint in it to see the state of your communication results.

Comment: My guess is that you need to wait for the first `BeginSend` to finish before invoking the next call to `BeginSend`.  Try replacing `BeginSend` with `Send` to see if your problem goes away.  If so, you know you need to wait on your async operations to finish first.

Comment: The protocals are TCP. The Callback checks for length prefix and won't return a packet unless it is correct. Send does not solve this issue. 

The server acts as an authoratative server. The clients are connected to it and send to it. The Server re-broadcasts to specific clients the message. The server stores packets into a Queue and then whena new client joins it re-sends that queue to the client. That is is where my issue is. All other send methods work as expected.

Comment: Is your socket in nonblocking mode? If Socket.Blocking = false, you need to do your own buffering.

Answer (score 2):

I would suspect that you are flooding the TCP port with packets, and probably overflowing its send buffer, at which point it will probably return errors rather than sending the data.

The idea of Async I/O is not to allow you to send an infinite amount of data packets simultaneously, but to allow your foreground thread to continue processing while a *linear sequence* of one or more I/O operations occurs in the background.

As the TCP stream is a serial stream, try respecting that and send each packet in turn. That is, after BeginSend, use the Async callback to detect when the Send has completed before you send again. You are effectively doing this by adding a Sleep, but this is not a very good solution (you will either be sending packets more slowly than possible, or you may not sleep for long enough and packets will be lost again)

Or, if you don't need the I/O to run in the background, use your simple foreach loop, but use a synchronous rather than Async send.

Comment: Your answer perfectly describes my situation. This has solved my problem thank you.

Comment: @Devon: You should accept this answer by clicking the hollow check.

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

Apparently a fix, so far still has me confused, is to Thread.Sleep for the number of ms for each packet I am sending.

So...

```
for(int i = 0; i < PacketQueue.Count; i++)
{
     Packet packet = PacketQueue[i];
     clientSocket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(EndSend), data);
     Thread.Sleep(PacketQueue.Count);
}
```

I assume that for some reason the loop stops some of the calls from happening... Well I will continue to work with this and try to find the real answer.

Comment: Could anyone shed light on why you would need to sleep the thread when begin send creates an async thread to do the executing?